# How to create a list of related fields from the queryset result in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I would like to create a queryset from another one which is obtained from a filter search query.

There are my models :

```
class A(models.Model):
    b   = models.ForeignKey(B)
    c   = models.ForeignKey(C)
    score   = models.FloatField(default=5)
```

My first query is to filter `A` objects related to a particular `B` instance "`b_instance`":

```
a_list  = A.objects.filter(b=b_instance)
```

How can I obtain form "`a_list`", a "`c_list`" regrouping all "`c`" fields objects without refer to make a loop ?

Comment: Hi you might want to edit your answer so the english is more understandable, but perhaps you wanted `a_list.filter(c=c_instance)` or `a_list.values_list(c, flat=True)`

Comment: Thanks @hqtay: `a_list` is a list of `A` objects. From this list, I want to obtain a `c_list` containing all C fields (`a_instance.c`) without going by loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
c_list = a_list.values_list('c', flat=True)
```

would give a list of all the c values from the filtered A objects

Comment: That is great. Thanks a lot [hqtay](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1849196/hqtay) !!